# Real Time Audio Processing: audioDeviceReader 'Driver' not working (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, audio, real-time, audio-recording, asio

Im using Fireface UC audio interface.

```
setpref('dsp', 'portaudioHostApi', 3);
deviceReader = audioDeviceReader('Driver', 'ASIO', 'Device', 'ASIO Fireface USB', 'SamplesPerFrame', 1024, 'SampleRate', 48000);
deviceWriter = audioDeviceWriter('Driver', 'ASIO', 'Device', 'ASIO Fireface USB', 'SampleRate', 48000, 'BufferSize', 1024);
```

when I enable ASIO driver for eg in the above code, there is no output sound. The buffer size settings obtained from asiosettings(deviceWriter.Device) is set to 1024 as well.

However when ASIO driver is not enabled, for eg in the following code, there is real time output sound, but there is noticeable latency.

```
setpref('dsp', 'portaudioHostApi', 3);
deviceReader = audioDeviceReader('Device', 'Analog (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)', 'SamplesPerFrame', 1024, 'SampleRate', 48000);
deviceWriter = audioDeviceWriter('Device', 'Analog (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)', 'SampleRate', 48000, 'BufferSize', 1024);
```

How do I successfully enable ASIO in order to reduce real time audio latency???

edit: using matlab 2018b which has the audio system toolbox. Latency is reduced when buffersize is reduced to 64, which is the furthest I can go before clicks and pops occur.

However, it only works if I use ASIO for the mic, and WASAPI for the speaker, i.e.

```
setpref('dsp', 'portaudioHostApi', 3); 
deviceReader = audioDeviceReader('Driver', 'ASIO', 'Device', ASIO Fireface USB', 'SamplesPerFrame', 1024, 'SampleRate', 48000);
deviceWriter = audioDeviceWriter('Driver', 'WASAPI', 'Device', 'Analog (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)', 'SampleRate', 48000, 'BufferSize', 64);
```

why is this so? why cant i enable ASIO driver for both speaker and microphone?

Also, another problem faced is that there is echo from my speech, which is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to know which version of Matlab you are using, and if you have the Audio System Toolbox. Then, might I suggest this example that shows how to measure low latency:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/examples/measure-audio-latency.html

Comment: using matlab 2018b with audio system toolbox, edited original question as well. thanks for the suggestion, will try it out.